# Why removing docker containers and images does not free up storage space on Windows? How to fix it?

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

**Problem:**

As I download and run containers, they keep taking up more and more space. I found suggestions for cleaning up unused containers and images and I did so. Guess what? They eat up even more disk space!

**What I found so far:**

It has to do with `.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk` file. It only gets bigger!

**Log of disk.vmdk:**

```
                            size (MB)
1. with 2 images                1,376
2. downloading a new image X    ?
3. running X as Y               2,963
4. removing Y                   2,963
5. removing X                   3,106
6. removing all the images      3,126
```

The only fix I found so far was running `docker-machine rm default` which removes the VM. The problem is that I have to download all the images again. There should be a better fix. Can someone explain:

1. **What is going on?**
2. **How to fix it?**

Comment: Yes, that's correct, virtual disks only get bigger; virtual drivers don't know what part of the virtual disk is in use by the OS file system and what part isn't. It's all just bits.

Answer (score 41):

On windows 10, this was a major issue, space was not freeing up, even after I ran `docker system prune` I started noticing this when I found that every week; my SSD was filling up every2 or 3 GB of space.

> Try opening Docker Desktop, hitting the Troubleshoot icon at the top right of the UI, and then clicking "Clean / Purge data". This reclaimed the space for me.

Also see:

1. [Windows 10: Docker does not release disk space after deleting all images and containers
   #244](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/244#issuecomment-760894407)
2. [Hyper V ui issue fix](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/244#issuecomment-834326357)
3. [Clear Hyper-V recognize unused sectors](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/244#issuecomment-909661161)
4. [Linux growing docker size issue fix](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21925#issuecomment-208802740)

Comment: my SSD went from 37 to 54gb in free space after running that troubleshooter. Had also run `docker system prune` a couple of days ago. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks. after doing everything with docker prune, only this solution works in the end. Claimed back 24GB from Docker.

Comment: 69gb freed up, docker system prune didn't remove anything

Comment: Thanks my WSL2 was at 600GB, the design is extremely poor for Windows. Deleting images doesn't release the wsl space. It's pretty awful it will be the size of all containers and every time you delete a container it never releases and stays forever. if you run 2 images with 5gb it provisions the space and never releases. It was eating my C: drive like crazy 600gb on a 1tb m2 is significant

Answer (score 38):

There are maintainance commands you can run on the more recent versions of Docker. They will free up space used by stopped containers, dangling images and dangling volumes:

```
docker container prune -f
docker image prune -f
docker volume prune -f
```

Comment: There is a combined one as well: docker system prune

Comment: Also, it has been mentioned in other posts that space is freed, after restarting docker desktop

Comment: Yep, restarting docker desktop worked for me.

Comment: Note that `docker system prune` doesn't actually remove the volumes by default. To also remove volumes, you should use: `docker system prune --volumes`.

Comment: My issue was with the volumes not getting cleared out after wiping the image. This would be the `docker volume prune` option.

Answer (score 18):

On windows using wsl2 follow the below steps. **Note that you will lose all the docker images and containers if you follow this.**
If you want to retain data(images and containers) then you can try the prune option mentioned by other people on this thread.

Locate the vhdx file where docker stores the data. This is a virtual hard disk used by docker.

```
"P:\Users\your-username\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx"
```

In my case docker is using up about 27GB of disk space in this file. Even after deleting all the images and container, docker is not releasing the free disk space back to OS.
[image]

To reclaim the disk space, you have to try **clean/purge data** option from the GUI. When prompted for the data set name, select WSL 2. This should clean up and give back all the unused space.

In case, the docker daemon doesn't start up or disk space is not reduced then the last option is to factory restore from docker desktop GUI like show below.
[image]

Comment: Clean/Purge data did the trick for me. `docker system prune` didn't help

Comment: Useful when you HDD or SDD is full.

Answer (score 10):

Docker cache: Docker uses a cache to improve build times and optimize image layering. The cache stores intermediate layers during the image build process. When you remove an image, Docker might still keep the cached layers, which consume disk space.

To clean up the Docker cache, you can use the docker system prune command. This command removes unused data, including cached layers. Be cautious, as it will also remove other unused resources such as containers and networks.

```
docker system prune
```

Additionally, if you want to specifically clean up only the cached image data, you can use the docker builder prune command:

```
docker builder prune
```

By using the methods mentioned above, you can ensure that both unused volumes and Docker cache are cleaned up, thus freeing up storage space on your Linux system.

Comment: The command "docker system prune" is actually enough for the task, it actually deletes all the caches, including "dangling build cache", which is deleted by the "docker builder prune" command.

Comment: @YaroslavVoytovych that's true! And with this option, I've freed almost 5 GB up!

Comment: Best answer! Just reposting what **jelleklaver** said on Jul 7, 2022: 
Note that `docker system prune` doesn't actually remove the volumes by default. To also remove volumes, you should use: `docker system prune --volumes`, or `docker volume prune -f`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the images you are using, use volumes. If they do then deleting the container doesn't do the trick. You must delete the volumes as well. 
In order to do that you must specify the `-v` flag when deleting a container

```
docker rm -v <container name or container id>
```

Depending on your docker version you will have some more commands available.
Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers) for more. You can read more about orphaned volumes in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812807/orphaned-docker-mounted-host-volumes)

Comment: What docker version are you using?

Comment: `Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990`

Comment: Try `docker volume ls`

Comment: I tried it before following the link you provided in the answer. There are no volumes.

Comment: btw, I am testing using `ubuntu` image.

Comment: Then maybe the logs are causing this behaviour? Do you have a lot of logs? Although I think deleting the container, deletes the logs as well, but I'm not sure. Check this http://serverfault.com/questions/637996/clearing-deleting-docker-logs

Comment: I am actually not using these test containers. I simply `run -it --name ubu ubuntu` > `rm -v ubu` > `rmi ubuntu`.

Answer (score 6):

After deleting all the unwanted containers and images using the commands below:

- Docker container rm
- Docker image rm
- Docker container prune
- Docker image prune
- Docker volume prune

I couldn't see any disk space released. I found out the disk space was released after I restarted my Docker desktop.

Comment: Good to know. I deleted a huge image, but I got back my disk space only after restart my Docker.

Comment: worked for me. Commands to restart docker on linux:  `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, 
 `sudo systemctl restart docker` https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

Comment: I did all of the above, but I didn't get any disk space back after restarting Docker Desktop (on Windows 10).

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is struggling with this problem on Ubuntu:

In my case pruning and removing using the docker command did not help much.

The issue was `docker/overlay2` folder.

```
febrin@laptop:/var/lib$ sudo du -sh docker/overlay2
361G    docker/overlay2
```

I had to delete it manually.

Comment: I used, `sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/overlay2`, freed so much space, thank you in GB

Comment: This works (but I guess this will delete *all* volumes, so if only want to remove some volumes, use `docker inspect` to find out where they're stored.

But it doesn't explain how these volumes end up in an un-prunable state in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

If you also can't free up space as troubleshoot->Clear/Purge answers with an error message:

```
wslconfig /unregister docker-desktop
wslconfig /unregister docker-desktop-data
```

Found it here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7295#issuecomment-653815064

This unregisters distributions running in your wsl. You can see your distributions with `wsl -l -v`.

My disk space was released immediately after running the second command (docker-desktop-data)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue while doing docker-compose up I was getting some error due to dependency issues in my `requirements.txt` file because of which my images and containers were not getting created but my disk space was getting reduced.

I first had to resolve the dependency issues after which my images and containers were created and then

As mentioned above by other users doing Clean/Purge through the troubleshoot UI freed my disk space.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I deleted the WSL distro data manually from the docker folder in

```
AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data
```

after that just run the following command

```
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
```

and restart docker desktop
it worked for me!