# how to find docker image and it's related subvolumes

Tags: docker

we have some docker server built, but when the old image/container gets renewed/removed the old subvolumes are not deleted, so it now end up with we have 10 running images/containers but 50+ subvolumes, it fill up the filesystems pretty quick.

we would like to delete those subvolumes which are no longer needed but how do we find these subvoluems not anymore related to the images/containers?

thanks

Eric

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Orphaned Docker mounted host volumes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812807/orphaned-docker-mounted-host-volumes)

Comment: I've added a `docker volume prune` answer to the above dupe